# How to fix java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858 error?

Tags: spring, oracle, mybatis

I have a module in my system wherein the system ask a user to input two dates.

The system will use the two dates to get reports from the system.

My problem is with the query, the error is

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I don't know what the problem is

When I run this in navicat, it's working.

I've tried to remove the `to_date`, solutions here in stackoverflow said that I should use `to_char` but the input of the user is a `String`.

I'm out of options.

Here is the query

```
SELECT refer."DATE", 
        doc."DOCUMENTED_COMPLAINTS", 
        resolved."RESOLVED_COMPLAINTS", 
        dispatched."DISPATCHED_CREW", 
        intr."INTERRUPTION"
        FROM 
        (select 
           TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(#{dateFrom},'MM/DD/YYYY') + rownum -1),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "DATE"
        from 
           all_objects
        where 
           rownum &lt;= 
           TO_DATE(#{dateTo},'MM/DD/YYYY')-TO_DATE(#{dateFrom},'MM/DD/YYYY')+1) refer
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_CREATED,'MM/DD/YYYY') as "CNR_DATE" , COUNT(TICKET_NO) as "DOCUMENTED_COMPLAINTS"
        FROM CNR_TICKET 
        WHERE CREATED_BY = #{name}
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_CREATED,'MM/DD/YYYY')) doc
        ON refer."DATE" = doc."CNR_DATE"
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_CLOSED,'MM/DD/YYYY') as "CNR_DATE", COUNT(TICKET_NO) as "RESOLVED_COMPLAINTS"
        FROM CNR_TICKET
        WHERE CLOSED_BY = #{name}
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_CLOSED,'MM/DD/YYYY')) resolved
        on refer."DATE" = resolved."CNR_DATE"
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT TO_CHAR(ACTION_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') as "DISPATCH_DATE", COUNT(TICKET_NO) as "DISPATCHED_CREW"
        FROM CNR_DIARY
        WHERE UPDATED_BY = #{name} AND CREW != null
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ACTION_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')) dispatched
        on refer."DATE" = dispatched."DISPATCH_DATE"
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT TO_CHAR(INTERRUPTIONTS,'MM/DD/YYYY') as "INTR_DATE", COUNT(ID) as "INTERRUPTION"
        FROM INTERRUPTIONS
        WHERE OPERATOR = #{name} AND DELETED = '0'
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(INTERRUPTIONTS,'MM/DD/YYYY')) intr
        ON refer."DATE" = intr."INTR_DATE"
        ORDER BY TO_DATE(refer."DATE",'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Sample input

```
Input 1 : 08/01/2019 : #{dateFrom}
Input 2 : 08/19/2019 : #{dateTo}
```

I can provide other codes you guys need. Just comment down. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide table definition of INTERRUPTIONS? It could be this condition "DELETED = '0'"

Answer (score 0):

I think all of your variables which are string must be wrapped in single quotes.

I tried to reproduce your issue i.e. using string without single quotes in `TO_DATE` function.

```
select TO_DATE(11/11/2019,'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

Error:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

-- Correct format:
select TO_DATE('11/11/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
```

See the **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5af7ba62c0a9672dd7457cc2f1c9920)** with error and corrected example.

So you will need to use single quotes as shown in the following example:

```
TO_DATE('#{dateTo}','MM/DD/YYYY') -- notice the single quotes around your variable name
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I don't think that the variables should be wrapped in single quotes, variables from my other codes are not wrapped in single quotes but they are working fine, Thanks for answering tho. Cheers! Could it be that the error is from the rownum?

Comment: Ok. Actually I am core oracle developer  and interestingly, I reproduced the issue also. Hence I thought that may be the issue. It can not happen with rownum as date difference always gives a number. Though a suggestion, you can use `&le;` instead of `&lt;=`

Comment: wow that's really nice! What else could be the problem? :( Thanks for the tip of ```&le;```

Comment: One more suggestion, `CREW != null` --> this condition will always fails. You must use `CREW IS NOT NULL`

Comment: nice! Do you have any suggestion on how I can display dates? for example 1/02/2019 - 1/10/2019
OUTPUT:
1/02/2019
1/03/2019
1/04/2019
etc.
or is the query I'm using fine?

Comment: when I wrap the variables in single quotes, this is the error I get ```java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index```

Comment: You must use dates in your entire query except in select clause. Working with dates and join using dates will be simpler. At the end when it comes to display then only you need to use `to_char`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198125/discussion-between-patrick-brian-garcia-and-tejash).